Spring Cloud Request Rate Limiting using Hazelcast instead of Redis
I want to remove redis cache and use hazelcast. Please provide a sample.
Using this key with redis:
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[2].filters[2].name= RequestRateLimiter

Want same functionality except cache being hazelcast
